# handling wildcard search with Special character in Lucene.net search

Tags: special-characters, lucene.net, wildcard

how do i perform wildcard search a word in lucene that contain special character. for example i have a word like "**91-95483534**" if i search like "**91***" it works and if i search like "91-95483534" also works fine. but my senario is that to search "**91-9548***". if i perform like this "**91-9548***". i got no output. am i missing anything. my actual code is given below:

```
MultiFieldQueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new string[] {"column1","column2"}, new StandardAnalyzer());

queryParser.SetAllowLeadingWildcard(true);

Query query = queryParser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(strKeyWord) + "*");
```

Answer (score 1):

As you used StandardAnalyzer, that indexed your word as 91 and 95483534 if you used INDEX_ANALYZED when you index....
if you want to search as 91-9548* , use INDEX_NOT_ANALYZED when you index that specified field which have "91-95483534" as terms

http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.Index.html